# Send a email to my email automatically with javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, email, web-scraping, puppeteer

So this the problem: I want to know if theres a way to email me (with another address) when a certain event happen with javascript or nodejs for example.

```
if (100 > 90) { 
emailto="xxxxx.gmail.com" 
subject="It happen" } else do nothing
```

Things to make clear: English is not my first language, i'm making a scraper with nodejs and puppeteer, the scraper is mostly done and this would be my first "thing" in the programming world, Thanks.

Comment: You can definitely do it running an ajax request to a server who will send the mail for you..

Comment: That ajax comment applies to front-end, not node. You should look at a email api with a free tier.

Answer (score 0):

Install nodemailer on your install

https://nodemailer.com/about/

> Nodemailer is a module for Node.js applications to allow easy as cake email sending.